# VBS is executing through SSIS , but same cannot be done when scheduling the sql job

Tags: vbscript, ssis

I am executing a VBSCRIPT through SSIS, which is converting pivot to RAW CSV. In SSIS it's working but when scheduling it through SQL Server it's not working.
Note: No error in SQL Job, it says step completed successfully returned 0.

Comment: Check the actual SSIS log.

Comment: In your sln, go to Project >Properties >Configuration Properties >General >Target Server Version. Make sure it is set to the right server version (year) you are using.

Comment: SSIS may be using your windows auth but the SQL Server job may need elevated privileges, since the VBS script is manipulating files. Look into these instructions on how to create a proxy user to execute SSIS jobs. https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/129293-configure-an-ssis-package-to-execute-as-a-proxy-account

Comment: I am executing it through proxy, Job is running, No error ... But It is not doing what is suppose to do (i.e converting file to raw data file).

Comment: Any help would be appreciated! I am yet to solve it.